# core-scaffold element in Polymer 1.0

Tags: html, polymer

Where has the core-scaffold element gone in polymer 1.0?
I was expecting to find an Iron element that would do just the same, but a glance at the documentation proved me wrong.
This element was very useful to quickly set up a layout, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 1.0 we're using a combination of `<paper-drawer-panel>`, `<paper-toolbar>`, `<paper-header-panel>` and `<paper-toolbar>`.

In 1.0 [Polymer Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/index?hl=en) ([Github version](https://github.com/polymerelements/polymer-starter-kit)) will do all the scaffolding for you (or at least get you started).

It's super simple to do.

Just install `npm` and `yeoman` at your terminal. Then at your command line, just hit:

```
$ mkdir myproject
$ cd myproject
$ yo polymer
```

Then give it a few minutes to run and it scaffolds everything out nicely for you. If you want to make a custom element, just do:

```
$ yo polymer:seed
```

and you're all set.

#### Bonus Update

Recently, there was an amazing video posted by Rob Dodson of the Polymer team about how to take your project "end-to-end" using Polymer! [Check it out here!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1f_Tj_JnStA) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1f_Tj_JnStA

Answer (score 1):

As Mowzer already stated you can recreate the core-scaffold element by making use of the paper elements in Polymer 1.0. The following snippet should create something very similar to what you are looking for:

```html
<paper-drawer-panel>
  <paper-header-panel drawer>
    <paper-toolbar>
      <div>Application</div>
    </paper-toolbar>
    <div> Drawer content...</div>
  </paper-header-panel>
  <paper-header-panel main>
    <paper-toolbar>
      <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div>Title</div>
    </paper-toolbar>
    <div> Main content...</div>
  </paper-header-panel>
</paper-drawer-panel>
```

Just make sure you setup your imports properly and you should be good to go.